# Tan of difference of two angles given as sum of sines and cosines

Tags: functions, trigonometry, radicals, fractions, trigonometric-integrals

I could have done the question had it been to find the value of $\tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$. But here the tangent of the difference has been asked. How does one go about it?

> If $\sin\alpha + \sin\beta = a$ and $\cos\alpha + \cos\beta = b$, then show that 
>   $$\tan\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{4-a^2-b^2}{a^2 + b^2}}.$$

Comment: If you could have done it with $\tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}2$, then do it in this way, and then change the sign of every $\beta$ (that is, $\beta\mapsto-\beta$), and you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) for $\tan$, we have $$\tan\frac{\alpha-\beta}2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{1+\cos(\alpha-\beta)}}\tag{1}$$

Now $$a^2=(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)^2=\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+2\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$ $$b^2=(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)^2=\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+2\cos\alpha\cos\beta$$ so

$$a^2 + b^2=2+2(\sin\alpha\sin\beta+\cos\alpha\cos\beta)=2(1+\cos(\alpha-\beta))$$ Hence $$\pm\sqrt{\frac{4-a^2-b^2}{a^2 + b^2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{4-2(1+\cos(\alpha-\beta))}{2(1+\cos(\alpha-\beta))}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{1+\cos(\alpha-\beta)}}$$ which is the same as $(1)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where equation $(1)$ comes from?

Comment: @JohnDoe Half Angle formula connecting tan and cos

Comment: @JohnDoe Provided link; seventh identity down.

Answer (score 4):

Use $$a^2+b^2=2+\cos(\alpha-\beta).$$
We obtain:
$$\sqrt{\frac{4-a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2-2\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{2+2\cos(\alpha-\beta)}}=\left|\tan\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right|$$

Answer (score 2):

For $0 \leq \beta \leq \alpha \leq 90^\circ$ ...

[image]

$$\tan\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} = \frac{d}{c} = \sqrt{\frac{2^2-c^2}{c^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{4-\left(a^2+b^2\right)}{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: (+1) amazing! How did you even think about drawing such a diagram in the first place?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Thanks! :) It's kinda what I do. (Shameless plug: See http://trigonography.com .) In this case, the conditions $\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=a$ and $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=b$ suggest a fairly "obvious" configuration to try as a setup, especially given the appearance of $a^2+b^2$ in the target relation. From there, I needed to make $(\alpha-\beta)/2$ appear (not too difficult); with the tangent of that angle being "opposite over adjacent", and with "adjacent" being known, I simply had to introduce "opposite" ($d$) and observe that the $c$-$d$ triangle had an "obvious" hypotenuse of $2$.